# How does this sequence of expressions continue?

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations, recreational-mathematics, generating-functions

I have the following sequence of expressions (question marks denote unknown numbers):

1. $1^k x$
2. $2^k x² − (1 × 1^k +  1 × 2^k) x$
3. $3^k x³ − (2 × 2^k +  3 × 3^k) x² + ( 2 × 1^k +  2 × 2^k +  2 × 3^k) x$
4. $4^k x⁴ − (3 × 3^k +  6 × 4^k) x³ + ( 6 × 2^k +  9 × 3^k + 11 × 4^k) x² − (6 × 1^k + 6 × 2^k + 6 × 3^k + 6 × 4^k) x$
5. $5^k x⁵ − (4 × 4^k + 10 × 5^k) x⁴ + (12 × 3^k + 24 × 4^k + 35 × 5^k) x³ − (24 × 2^k + 36 × 3^k + 44 × 4^k + 50 × 5^k) x² + (24 × 1^k + 24 × 2^k + 24 × 3^k + 24 × 4^k + 24 × 5^k) x$
6. $6^k x⁶ − (5 × 5^k + 15 × 6^k) x⁵ + (20 × 4^k + 50 × 5^k + 85 × 6^k) x⁴ − (60 × 3^k + 120 × 4^k + 175 × 5^k + 225 × 6^k) x³ + (120 × 2^k + 180 × 3^k + 220 × 4^k + 250 × 5^k + 274 × 6^k) x² − (120 × 1^k + 120 × 2^k + 120 × 3^k + 120 × 4^k + 120 × 5^k + 120 × 6^k) x$
7. $7^k x⁷ − (6 × 6^k + 21 × 7^k) x⁶ + (30 × 5^k + 90 × 6^k + 175 × 7^k) x⁵ − (120 × 4^k + 300 × 5^k + 510 × 6^k + 735 × 7^k) x⁴ + (360 × 3^k + 720 × 4^k + 1050 × 5^k + 1350 × 6^k + 1624 × 7^k) x³ − ( ? × 2^k +  ? × 3^k +  ? × 4^k +  ? × 5^k +  ? × 6^k +  ? × 7^k) x² + (720 × 1^k + 720 × 2^k + 720 × 3^k + 720 × 4^k + 720 × 5^k + 720 × 6^k + 720 × 7^k) x$

## The Problem

**I want to know how to continue this sequence.** That is, how to fill in the missing numbers in the seventh expression in the sequence, and how to construct the eighth and ninth and twelfth and so on expressions in the sequence.

Some patterns immediately stand out:

- The expressions are polynomials in terms of $x$, with coefficients composed of sums of numbers in the form in the form $(a × b^k)$, where $a$ and $b$ are positive integers
- The coefficient for the $m$th term in all expressions is a sum of $(m + 1)$ numbers in the form $(a × b^k)$
- The $n$th expression is $n$ terms long, with highest degree $n$ and containing terms of all lower degrees down to and including 1, with zero constant term
- The zeroth term in the $n$th expression is $n^k × x^n$
- The first term in the $n$th expression is $−\left((n − 1) × (n − 1)^k + \frac{n² − n}{2} × n^k\right) × x^{n − 1}$
- The second term in the $n$th expression is $\left((n² − 3 n + 2) × (n − 2)^k + \frac{n³ − 4 n² + 5 n − 2}{2} × (n − 1)^k + \frac{3 n⁴ − 10 n³ + 9 n² − 2 n}{24} × n^k\right) × x^{n − 2}$
- The third term in the $n$th expression is $−\left((n³ - 6 n² + 11 n - 6) × (n − 3)^k + \frac{n⁴ - 8 n³ + 23 n² - 28 n + 12}{2} × (n − 2)^k + \frac{3 n⁵ - 25 n⁴ + 79 n³ - 119 n² + 86 n - 24}{8} × (n − 1)^k + \frac{n⁶ - 7 n⁵ + 17 n⁴ - 17 n³ + 6 n²}{48} × n^k\right) × x^{n − 3}$
- The $(n − 1)$th term (the last non-zero term) in the $n$th expression is $(−1)^{n − 1} × (n − 1)! × (1^k + 2^k + 3^k + \, ... + (n − 1)^k + n^k) × x$
- The terms alternate positive and negative — the zeroth is always positive, the first is always negative, the second is always positive, and so on
- The bases $b$ of the exponential numbers $(a × b^k)$ in the $m$th term in the $n$th expression are one higher than the bases of the corresponding numbers in the $m$th term of the $(n − 1)$th expression

To break it down, here are the coefficients of the zeroth terms in all the expressions:

1. $1^k$
2. $2^k$
3. $3^k$
4. $4^k$
5. $5^k$
6. $6^k$
7. $7^k$

- $n^k$

Here are the coefficients of the first terms in all the expressions:

1. $0 × 0^k +  0 × 1^k$
2. $1 × 1^k +  1 × 2^k$
3. $2 × 2^k +  3 × 3^k$
4. $3 × 3^k +  6 × 4^k$
5. $4 × 4^k + 10 × 5^k$
6. $5 × 5^k + 15 × 6^k$
7. $6 × 6^k + 21 × 7^k$

- $(n − 1) × (n − 1)^k + \frac{n² − n}{2} × n^k$

Here are the coefficients of the second terms in all the expressions:

1. $ 0 × −1^k +  0 × 0^k +   0 × 1^k$
2. $ 0 ×  0^k +  0 × 1^k +   0 × 2^k$
3. $ 2 ×  1^k +  2 × 2^k +   2 × 3^k$
4. $ 6 ×  2^k +  9 × 3^k +  11 × 4^k$
5. $12 ×  3^k + 24 × 4^k +  35 × 5^k$
6. $20 ×  4^k + 50 × 5^k +  85 × 6^k$
7. $30 ×  5^k + 90 × 6^k + 175 × 7^k$

- $(n² − 3 n + 2) × (n − 2)^k + \frac{n³ − 4 n² + 5 n − 2}{2} × (n − 1)^k + \frac{3 n⁴ − 10 n³ + 9 n² − 2 n}{24} × n^k$

Here are the coefficients of the third terms in all the expressions:

1. $  0 × −2^k +   0 × −1^k +   0 × 0^k +   0 × 1^k$
2. $  0 × −1^k +   0 ×  0^k +   0 × 1^k +   0 × 2^k$
3. $  0 ×  0^k +   0 ×  1^k +   0 × 2^k +   0 × 3^k$
4. $  6 ×  1^k +   6 ×  2^k +   6 × 3^k +   6 × 4^k$
5. $ 24 ×  2^k +  36 ×  3^k +  44 × 4^k +  50 × 5^k$
6. $ 60 ×  3^k + 120 ×  4^k + 175 × 5^k + 225 × 6^k$
7. $120 ×  4^k + 300 ×  5^k + 510 × 6^k + 735 × 7^k$

- $(n³ − 6 n² + 11 n − 6) × (n − 3)^k + \frac{n⁴ − 8 n³ + 23 n² − 28 n + 12}{2} × (n − 2)^k + \frac{3 n⁵ − 25 n⁴ + 79 n³ − 119 n² + 86 n − 24}{24} × (n − 1)^k + \frac{n⁶ − 7 n⁵ + 17 n⁴ − 17 n³ + 6 n²}{48} × n^k$

Here are the coefficients of the fourth terms in all the expressions (note that I don't know the pattern for the last number in each coefficient):

1. $  0 × −3^k +   0 × −2^k +    0 × −1^k +    0 × 0^k +    0 × 1^k$
2. $  0 × −2^k +   0 × −1^k +    0 ×  0^k +    0 × 1^k +    0 × 2^k$
3. $  0 × −1^k +   0 ×  0^k +    0 ×  1^k +    0 × 2^k +    0 × 3^k$
4. $  0 ×  0^k +   0 ×  1^k +    0 ×  2^k +    0 × 3^k +    0 × 4^k$
5. $ 24 ×  1^k +  24 ×  2^k +   24 ×  3^k +   24 × 4^k +   24 × 5^k$
6. $120 ×  2^k + 180 ×  3^k +  220 ×  4^k +  250 × 5^k +  274 × 6^k$
7. $360 ×  3^k + 720 ×  4^k + 1050 ×  5^k + 1350 × 6^k + 1624 × 7^k$

- $(n⁴ − 10 n³ + 35 n² − 50 n + 24) × (n − 4)^k + \frac{n⁵ − 13 n⁴ + 65 n³ − 155 n² + 174 n − 72}{2} × (n − 3)^k + \frac{3 n⁶ − 43 n⁵ + 249 n⁴ − 745 n³ + 1212 n² − 1012 n + 336}{24} × (n − 2)^k + \frac{n⁷ − 14 n⁶ + 80 n⁵ − 242 n⁴ + 419 n³ − 416 n² + 220 n − 48}{48} × (n − 1)^k + ??? × n^k$

However, I have been unable to figure out patterns for constructing the terms that fall between the third and last terms in the expressions.

## Where the Expressions Come From

The expressions generate numbers to be added as constants when developing the piecewise equations for an [Irwin-Hall distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution) (IHD), a probability distribution of a number $n$ of independent uniformly-distributed random variables. The probability density function (PDF) of an IHD of $n$ variables is a piecewise polynomial function consisting of $n$ segments of degree $(n − 1)$. The Cumulative Distribution Function (CDF) of an IHD of $n$ variables is a piecewise polynomial function consisting of $n$ segments of degree $n$.

Wikipedia gives this expression for the PDF of an IHD of $n$ variables:

$$f_X(x; n) = \frac{1}{2(n − 1)!} \sum_{k = 0}^n {\left((−1)^k {n \choose k} (x − k)^{n − 1} \operatorname{sgn}(x − k)\right)}$$

However, this does not directly give the piecewise polynomial form of the PDF. I want to find a way to generate the piecewise polynomial directly. This question is part of my efforts to do so.

The $(n − 1)$th derivative of the $m$th segment in the PDF (and the $n$th derivative of the $m$th segment in the CDF) of an IHD of $n$ variables is a constant term of the form $\frac{(−1)^m (n − 1)!}{m! (n − 1 − m)!}$. For example, in the case of four variables, the 3rd derivatives of the four segments of the PDF are:

0. $\frac{ (4 − 1)!}{0! (4 − 1 − 0)!} = \frac{ 3!}{0! 3!} =  1$
1. $\frac{−(4 − 1)!}{1! (4 − 1 − 1)!} = \frac{−3!}{1! 2!} = −3$
2. $\frac{ (4 − 1)!}{2! (4 − 1 − 2)!} = \frac{ 3!}{2! 1!} =  3$
3. $\frac{−(4 − 1)!}{3! (4 − 1 − 3)!} = \frac{−3!}{3! 0!} = −1$

In the case of five variables, the 4th derivatives of the five segments of the PDF are:

0. $\frac{ (5 − 1)!}{0! (5 − 1 − 0)!} = \frac{ 4!}{0! 4!} =  1$
1. $\frac{−(5 − 1)!}{1! (5 − 1 − 1)!} = \frac{−4!}{1! 3!} = −4$
2. $\frac{ (5 − 1)!}{2! (5 − 1 − 2)!} = \frac{ 4!}{2! 2!} =  6$
3. $\frac{−(5 − 1)!}{3! (5 − 1 − 3)!} = \frac{−4!}{3! 1!} = −4$
4. $\frac{ (5 − 1)!}{4! (5 − 1 − 4)!} = \frac{ 4!}{4! 0!} =  1$

The full PDF of an IHD of $n$ variables can be obtained by integrating these base numbers $(n − 1)$ times, adding a new constant term each time. The full CDF of an IHD of $n$ variables can be obtained by continuing the process one additional time. The constant terms to be added follow a specific pattern for each segment. I obtained the sequences of constant terms for each segment by trial and error, making a guess and then refining it until it lined up with the previous segment. I then used WolframAlpha to find the expressions that produce those constant terms for a given number $n$ of variables after $k$ integrations, giving rise to the sequence of equations that is the topic of this question.

0. The constant we add to the integrations of the zeroth segment is always zero
1. The constant we add to the integrations of the first segment is given by the sequence of expressions $\{n, \frac{−n}{2}, \frac{n}{6}, \frac{−n}{24}, \frac{n}{120}, \frac{−n}{720}, \, … \} = \frac{(−1)^k n}{0! × (k + 1)!}$
2. The constant we add to the integrations of the second segment is given by the sequence of expressions $\{−(n² − 2n), \frac{2n² − 3n}{2}, \frac{−(4n² − 5n)}{6}, \frac{8n² − 9n}{24}, \frac{−(16n² − 17n)}{120}, \frac{32n² − 33n}{720}, \, … \} = \frac{(−1)^{k + 1} (2^k n² − (1 + 2^k) n)}{1! × (k + 1)!}$
3. The constant we add to the integrations of the third segment is given by the sequence of expressions $\{\frac{n³ − 5n² + 6n}{2}, \frac{−(3n³ − 13n² + 12n)}{4}, \frac{9n³ − 35n² + 28n}{12}, \frac{−(27n³ − 97n² + 72n)}{48}, \frac{81n³ − 275n² + 196n}{240}, \frac{−(243n³ − 793n² + 552n)}{1440}, \, … \} = \frac{(−1)^k (3^k n³ − (2 × 2^k +  3 × 3^k) n² + 2! (1 + 2^k + 3^k) n)}{2! × (k + 1)!}$
4. The constant we add to the integrations of the fourth segment is given by the sequence of expressions $\{\frac{n⁴ − 9n³ + 26n² − 24n}{6}, \frac{−(4n⁴ − 33n³ + 83n² − 60n)}{12}, \frac{16n⁴ − 123n³ + 281n² − 180n}{36}, \frac{−(64n⁴ − 465n³ + 995n² − 600n)}{144}, \frac{256n⁴ − 1779n³ + 3641n² − 2124n}{720}, \frac{−(1024n⁴ − 6873n³ + 13643n² − 7800n)}{4320}, \, … \} = \frac{(−1)^k (4^k n⁴ − (3 × 3^k + 6 × 4^k) n³ + (6 × 2^k + 9 × 3^k + 11 × 4^k) n² − 3! (1 + 2^k + 3^k + 4^k) n)}{3! × (k + 1)!}$

### An Example of the Process

The equation for the third segment ($m = 3$) after three integrations ($k = 3$) is:

$$\int \left( \int \left( \int \left( \frac{(−1)^3 (n − 1)!}{3! (n − 1 − 3)!} \right) + \frac{n³ − 5n² + 6n}{2! × 1!} \right) − \frac{3n³ − 13n² + 12n}{2! × 2!} \right) + \frac{9n³ − 35n² + 28n}{2! × 3!}$$

In the case of four variables ($n = 4$), that simplifies to:

$$\int \left( \int \left( \int \left( −1 \right)  + 4 \right) − 8 \right) + \frac{32}{3}$$

Which expands into:

$$\frac{−x³}{6} + 2x² − 8x + \frac{32}{3}$$

Which can be re-written as:

$$\frac{−x³ + 12x² − 48x + 64}{3!}$$

Doing this for the other three segments in the PDF of the IHD of four variables gives the piecewise polynomial:

$$f_X(x; 4) = \begin{cases}
\frac{x³}{3!} & : 0 ≤ x ≤ 1 \\
\frac{−3x³ + 12x² − 12x + 4}{3!} & : 1 ≤ x ≤ 2 \\
\frac{3x³ − 24x² + 60x − 44}{3!} & :  2 ≤ x ≤ 3 \\
\frac{−x³ + 12x² − 48x + 64}{3!} & :  3 ≤ x ≤ 4 \\
0 & : \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

### Back to the Problem

The expressions for the $m$th segment are all divided by $((m − 1)! × (k + 1)!)$. When $m$ is even, the expressions are multiplied by $(−1)^{k + 1}$. When $m$ is odd, the expressions are multiplied by $(−1)^k$. Removing these known factors and replacing the $n$s with $x$s leaves the polynomials that are the basis of this question.

Here are the numbers I've worked out for the seventh expression in the sequence, which is as far as I can get with WolframAlpha:

0. $1 x⁷ −  27 x⁶ +  295 x⁵ −  1665 x⁴ +  5104 x³ −  8028 x² +  5040 x$

   - 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 8, 63, 280, 924, 2520, 6006, 12936, 25740, ...
1. $7 x⁷ − 183 x⁶ + 1915 x⁵ − 10185 x⁴ + 28678 x³ − 39672 x² + 20160 x$

   - 1, −2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 64, 495, 2170, 7084, 19152, 45318, 97020, 192060, ...
2. …

Comment: Could the people who voted to close for "Needs details or clarity" please leave a comment saying what other details I should include, or what needs clarification, so I can fix the problems?

Comment: How are you generating the initial polynomials? There has to be some sort of recurrence you are following, otherwise the combinations can be infinite. It is clear you are trying to transform the bi-variate polynomials in terms of $x$, but without your initial start, we can't help you.

Comment: It seems like only the part about the Irwin Hall distribution is relevant? I.e. technically there is no "unique" way to continue a finite sequence to an infinite sequence, unless we have placed constraints defining the infinite sequence. It seems like only the part about the irwin-hall distribution is relevant for the defining constraints of the infinite sequence. In any case this is very long and thus very difficult to organize how to read the question -- where is the most essential information located -- e.g. what are you asking, what might one need to know in order to answer, etc.

Comment: @Chill2Macht I moved the information about the IHD earlier in the text. If you have any other suggestions or insight, please let me know.

Comment: Question/clarification: is this question talking about the coefficients that show up in the PDF or CDF of the Irwin-Hall distribution? The Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irwin%E2%80%93Hall_distribution you linked to gives an explicit recurrence relation for those, which is in general the best one can do. The corresponding OEIS article does not seem to have any leads/follow-ups either https://oeis.org/A188816 I don't know what the generating function looks like, cf. slide 13 of these slides https://www.math.cmu.edu/~af1p/Teaching/Combinatorics/Slides/Generating-Functions.pdf

Comment: Again, I don't really quite understand what the question is asking, e.g. you show a lot of work for what you have done already, but I don't even understand what questions that work is answering, if that makes sense. E.g. I don't understand what you mean by "differentiating the segment". Presumably you are talking about the coefficients of the spline defining the probability density function? If so, again, an explicit recurrence relation for those is already known/given. So if anything better can be done than that, it is probably limited to calculating a generating function. If the coefficient

Comment: sequences had a closed form as a polynomial sequence/expression, I really doubt they wouldn't have just been given in that form. Also, for all practical purposes, unlesss for some reason you need the exact values for the IHD corresponding to the sum of $10^6$ iid uniforms, the explicit recurrence relations should be enough to write a computer program for in a Jupyter notebook https://jupyter.org/try https://cocalc.com/features/jupyter-notebook https://colab.research.google.com The number of terms to compute is sure $\approx O(n^3)$ but even for $100 < n < 1000$ that might still be reasonable.

Comment: I would strongly recommend editing the post to mention the explicit recurrence relations given in the Wikipedia article, and (if that is what the question is about) making it clear that you are looking for a non-recursive way to compute the coefficients. If so, maybe adding the "recurrence-relation" and "generating-function" tags would help. Making such major edits to your post when I'm not even sure I actually understand it seems not a good idea for me to do on your behalf. So you would really need to make those edits/rephrase the question yourself unfortunately.

Comment: @Chill2Macht I tried to clarify my question based on your feedback.

Comment: To clarify, I was referring to the formulae $f_X(x;n) = 1/(n-1)! \sum_{j=0}^{n-1} a_j(k,n)x^j$ "where the coefficients $a_j(k,n)$ may be found from a recurrence relation over $k$": $a_j(k,n) = a_j(k-1,n) + (-1)^{n+k-j-1}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{j}k^{n-j-1}$. Why is that insufficient? Have you tried to solve the recurrence relation? http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_recurrence.html Is that what you are trying to do? Why do you think it _can_ be solved? Etc. If all you want is to know how to generate the coefficients _somehow_, the recurrence relation already gives enough information.

Comment: @Chill2Macht I was playing around with the IHD and noticed a pattern in the numbers, and when playing around with that I noticed a pattern in the patterns of numbers, and I want to see how far I can take that. I know there are other ways of getting the same result, but my end goal isn't the result itself, it's this particular path towards that result.

Comment: If both paths lead to the same result, both paths should be equivalent. So if you want to understand "your" path better, it seems that the best approach/line of attack would be to first understand to what extent/how your approach compares with/is equivalent to the recurrence relation. E.g. with regards to the section "some patterns that stand out", it should be possible to prove (or disprove) that these hold for arbitrary $n$ using the recurrence relation. "An example the process" could probably be modified to give an inductive proof of the recurrence relation

Comment: @Chill2Macht I started a new question based on my attempt to understand the recurrence relation you pointed out: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4394497/can-this-recurrence-relation-be-solved-in-explicit-form

Answer (score 1):

(Probably doesn't answer the question but too long for a comment.) I honestly have no idea whether this is actually related, but just throwing this out there on a hunch because

(1) the kind of complicated but recursively patterned formulae for distributions looks similar,

(2) the same J.O. Irwin of the Irwin-Hall is actually cited in chapter 4 of the book,

but maybe some of the material talking about $k$-statistics, polykays, cumulants, or partition functions in the book [*Tensor Methods in Statistics*](https://web.archive.org/web/20201111124147/https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Epmcc/tensorbook/DoverEdition.pdf) by McCullagh might be relevant? ([searchable version](https://www.stat.uchicago.edu/%7Epmcc/tensorbook/DoverEdition.pdf))

For example compare pp. 107-108. Honestly even if it is related though, the level of prerequisite knowledge/understanding (e.g. of combinatorics/partition functions) required to meaningfully check whether the Irwin-Hall pattern actually shows up or not is fairly high. I don't understand the book myself.

Also I would say too that the more complicated patterns that arise naturally and are described in the book strongly seem to suggest that whatever heuristics (Lagrange interpolation?) Wolfram is using to come up with "most likely" polynomial generating functions for the terms are probably misleading. Unless you can prove why those formulae are valid for all $n$, I personally would not trust/take too seriously anything from Wolfram.

Irwin's paper about Irwin-Hall distribution citation:

> Irwin, J.O. (1927) "On the Frequency Distribution of the Means of Samples from a Population Having any Law of Frequency with Finite Moments, with Special Reference to Pearson's Type II". Biometrika, Vol. 19, No. 3/4., pp. 225–239. doi:10.1093/biomet/19.3-4.225 JSTOR 2331960

Cited paper by Irwin in *Tensor Methods in Statistics*:

> Irwin, J.O. and Kendall, M.G. (1943–45) "[Sampling moments of moments
> for a finite population](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/pdf/10.1111/j.1469-1809.1943.tb02315.x)". Ann. Eugenics 12, 138–142

^the name of that journal has *not* aged well, yeesh