# Can this recurrence relation be solved in explicit form?

Tags: recurrence-relations, generating-functions, closed-form

## Problem

We have the recurrence relation

$$a(j, k, n) = \begin{cases}
1 & : k = 0 ∧ j = n − 1 \\
0 & : k = 0 ∧ j < n − 1 \\
a(j, k − 1, n) + (−1)^{k + n − 1 − j} × \frac{n!} {k! (n − k)!} × \frac{(n − 1)!} {j! (n − 1 − j)!} × k^{n − 1 − j} & : k > 0
\end{cases}$$

Can this be converted to an explicit equation in terms of $j$, $k$, and $n$?

## Where the Relation Comes From

The recurrence relation generates coefficients for the piecewise equation of the Probability Density Function (PDF) of an Irwin-Hall Distribution (IHD), the sum of $n$ uniformly-distributed, independent, & random variables, over the interval $k ≤ x ≤ k + 1$. These coefficients are plugged into the expression

$$f_X(x;n) = \frac{1}{(n − 1)!} × \sum_{j = 0}^{n − 1} \left(a(j, k, n) × x^j\right)$$

to obtain the full equation.

## My Work So Far

It is known that the solution to a recurrence relation in the form $a(k) = a(k - 1) + f(k)$ is equal to $a(k) - a(0) = \sum_{m = 1}^k f(m)$. Thus, if $\sum_{m = 1}^k f(m)$ has a closed formula, you're good to go.

This recurrence relation does seem to be in that form, but I haven't been able to find a closed-form expression for $\sum_{m = 1}^k \left( (−1)^{m + n − 1 − j} × \frac{n!} {m! (n − m)!} × \frac{(n − 1)!} {j! (n − 1 − j)!} × m^{n − 1 − j} \right)$. I'm not sure if the presence of two additional variables makes this method invalid or just more complicated.

Evaluating that sum gives the infinite series

$$
\frac{n! × (n − 1)!} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \frac{(−1)^{n − j + 0} × 1^{n − 1 − j}} {1! × (n − 1)!} + \\
\frac{n! × (n − 1)!} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \frac{(−1)^{n − j + 1} × 2^{n − 1 − j}} {2! × (n − 2)!} + \\
\frac{n! × (n − 1)!} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \frac{(−1)^{n − j + 2} × 3^{n − 1 − j}} {3! × (n − 3)!} + \\
\frac{n! × (n − 1)!} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \frac{(−1)^{n − j + 3} × 4^{n − 1 − j}} {4! × (n − 4)!} + \\
\frac{n! × (n − 1)!} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \frac{(−1)^{n − j + 4} × 5^{n − 1 − j}} {5! × (n − 5)!} + \\
\frac{n! × (n − 1)!} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \frac{(−1)^{n − j + 5} × 6^{n − 1 − j}} {6! × (n − 6)!} + \\
…
$$

The partial sums of this infinite series are

1. $\frac{n! × (n − 1)! × (−1)^{n − j}} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \left(\frac{1^{n − 2 − j}} {0! × (n − 1)!}\right)$
2. $\frac{n! × (n − 1)! × (−1)^{n − j}} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \left(\frac{1^{n − 2 − j}} {0! × (n − 1)!} − \frac{2^{n − 2 − j}} {1! × (n − 2)!}\right)$
3. $\frac{n! × (n − 1)! × (−1)^{n − j}} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \left(\frac{1^{n − 2 − j}} {0! × (n − 1)!} − \frac{2^{n − 2 − j}} {1! × (n − 2)!} + \frac{3^{n − 2 − j}} {2! × (n − 3)!}\right)$
4. $\frac{n! × (n − 1)! × (−1)^{n − j}} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \left(\frac{1^{n − 2 − j}} {0! × (n − 1)!} − \frac{2^{n − 2 − j}} {1! × (n − 2)!} + \frac{3^{n − 2 − j}} {2! × (n − 3)!} − \frac{4^{n − 2 − j}} {3! × (n − 4)!}\right)$
5. $\frac{n! × (n − 1)! × (−1)^{n − j}} {j! × (n − 1 − j)!} × \left(\frac{1^{n − 2 − j}} {0! × (n − 1)!} − \frac{2^{n − 2 − j}} {1! × (n − 2)!} + \frac{3^{n − 2 − j}} {2! × (n − 3)!} − \frac{4^{n − 2 − j}} {3! × (n − 4)!} + \frac{5^{n − 2 − j}} {4! × (n − 5)!}\right)$
6. $…$

This pattern doesn't seem to collapse into a nice closed form, so it may be a dead end, but I don't know how to be sure.

Comment: Could you clarify how evaluating the (seemingly finite) sums gives an infinite series? Or is a generating function being used somewhere? (Also to be clear I almost certainly don't know how to answer this question either way, I'm just curious.)

Comment: @Chill2Macht My understanding, which may be incorrect or incomplete, comes from Example 2.4.3 in the resource you linked on my other question: http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi2/sec_recurrence.html

Comment: @Chill2Macht This specific method for solving a recurrence relation relies on turning the equation $a(n) = a(n - 1) + f(n)$ into the equivalent equation $a(n) -  a(n - 1) = f(n)$, evaluating it for infinite values of $n$, then summing up both sides of the equation to get:

 1. on the left, $(a(1) - a(0)) + (a(2) - a(1)) + (a(3) - a(2)) + (a(4) - a(3)) + … + (a(n) -  a(n - 1))$, which collapses (or "telescopes") into just $a(n) - a(0)$, and
 2. on the right, $f(1) + f(2) + f(3) + f(4) + … + f(n - 1) + f(n)$, which collapses into $\sum_{k = 1}^n f(k)$

Comment: Is there any reason you're writing out your binomial coefficients in terms of factorials? I feel like several of these formulas will be more comprehensible with binomial coefficients.

Comment: So it seems like we are talking about partial sums of an infinite sum then, so finite sums? Anyway I have to admit that mostly I have only ever heard of generating functions but never actually took a course in combinatorics or used a generating function to solve a problem, for homework or research or anything. That being said I agree with you that this is an interesting recurrence relation and hope that someone can answer the question.

Comment: This seems like it might be like the Mertens function https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mertens_function#Calculation in that clever algorithms can somewhat speed up computation relative to raw/brute force approach of directly summing up the terms in the recurrence relation, yet in effect computing its values is still greater than $O(1)$, which is what one would usually associate with a closed form expression (I think)? All of this is interesting to me to some extent but I am definitely not an expert unfortunately...

Comment: @StevenStadnicki It made more sense to me to perform calculations with the algebraic form of the binomial coefficient. I can try experimenting with them in nCr form if you think that would be better.